# Can you get a legitimate job?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In GTA V can you get a legitimate job, like a taxi driver? I was looking for a way to make cash without getting the cops on me. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, you can do taxi driver missions, but you won't get past the prologue, much less get far in the story if you're not willing to try out the Dark Side, young Padawan ;)

Comment: You can also tow people.  I suggest doing some research and reading a GTA5 wiki website.

Comment: I got money playing tennis, i am sure it's worth a try. but its GTA why bother getting a legitimate job

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can drive people in taxis for starters. What you can also do is help out the local forces (police, medics, firefighters).

Other than that there is now easy way to make cash without having the law on you. It's against GTA V fun.

Answer (score 13):

[Here is a link](http://www.gamingreality.com/2013/09/how-to-make-money-in-gta-5.html) to some activities that can earn you money in GTA 5.

The legal options include:

- **Taxi Missions** - Though getting the cab may require some petty crime.
- **Invest in a property**: You can buy a property which will earn you money or unlock missions.
- **Finding hidden collectibles**: Hidden packages are available immediately, but some of the other collectibles require unlocking.
- **Invest in the stock market**: Buy low, sell high.

Answer (score 1):

Stock market works too. You just invest more money that you get from doing taxi missions or whatever you want to do for legal jobs and it just puts more money into your in-game bank account.

Answer (score 1):

Purchase the docks in Paleto Bay and collect nuclear waste underwater. Each one is worth $25000 and there are 30 of them to collect.

Also, some random events reward you very well, and most involve helping people, rather than hurting them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get jobs, like vigilante missions, paramedic missions, firefighter missions, stock market, or taxi drivers. You can also just rob stores and kill people.

Answer (score -5):

Yes you can get a job on Grand Theft Auto V, but they are not very goods jobs. You can drive a taxi earing over $75 a ride, invest in a property(best one is golfing $1,500,00), help out police, medics, and/or firefighters, and when money is stolen from a person keep the money or get a $50 reward.

Comment: As a sidenote, vandalizing [other](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/56809) [people's](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/56810) answers is NOT the way to go about contributing here.

Comment: I wouldn't say that this is a intentional vandalizing. He does include more information like the amount of money from some of the jobs.